# get date of tomorrow using jstl

Tags: jsp, calendar, jstl

I tried the following to get the date of tomorrow in JSTL:

```
           <c:set var="currDate" value="<%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance()%>"/>
           <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${currDate.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE,1)}" var="dayEnd"/>
```

but when I printed out to check at least var currDate using

```
           <c:out value="${currDate}" />
```

apparently, it didn't work. What should i do then?

Comment: Compute the date in your controller, in Java, or encapsulate the computation in a custom tag?

Comment: @JBNizet: What do you mean exactly? I should not use JSTL for this? CMIIW

Comment: IMHO, no. JSPs are a view component. They should be used to generate markup, using a model that has been prepared and made available to the view by a controller. It's the controller's job to give the date to the view. If you think it's purely a view problem, then create a custom tag named `<myTag:tomorrow/>`

Comment: @JBNizet: Would it be better to give exact code snippet, perhaps? Maybe  I used wrong syntax or something so that i got no result as expected. Again, CMIIW

Comment: The format tag expects a java.util.Date. You could try using new java.util.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime() + 60*60*24*1000)

Comment: A code snippet to do what? Getting tomorrow as a calendar? You already have it. I'm just telling you not use it in the JSP, but in pure Java code, in your controller or in a custom JSP tag.

Comment: @rickz: thanks a lot. It really brought me a new idea. I just changed a bit and used like this: <c:set var="tomorrow" value="<%=new java.util.Date().getDate() + 1%>"/>

Comment: I thought you wanted to format the date. Anyway, getDate() is Deprecated. What will you do on the last day of the month? Just use my code to set your currDate

Comment: @rickz:What if i only want the day only? So, instead of Dec 4, 2012 GMT+7, I will get "4".

Comment: Please try my demo page in my answer below here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<c:set var="today" value="<%=new Date()%>"/>
<c:set var="tomorrow" value="<%=new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60*60*24*1000)%>"/>
Today: <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${today}" pattern="d"/>   
Tomorrow: <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${tomorrow}" pattern="d"/>
```

Comment: :thanks. i just found like this: <c:set var="tomorrow" value="<%=new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60*60*24*1000).getDate()%>"/>. Is it correct?

Answer (score 9):

There is neater way to do this directly in JSTL

```
<jsp:useBean id="ourDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="ourDate" property="time" value="${ourDate.time + 86400000}"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${ourDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

But you can't rely on java.util.Date when the clocks change to Summer Time for example.

So if you REALLY want to do this all in JSTL, you can, with Spring tags, Joda Time classes and Joda Tags.

```
    <jsp:useBean id="ourDate" class="org.joda.time.DateTime"/>
    <spring:eval expression="ourDate.plusDays(1)" var="tomorrow"/>
    tomorrow: <joda:format value="${tomorrow}" style="SM" />
```

The spring eval tag lets you do some of those naughty things we all used to do with scriptlets, and JodaTime can be trusted to always give you an accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(today.get(Calendar.YEAR),today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

// Convert the date string into a date to manipulate the dates
String year = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("year");
String month = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("month");
String day = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("day");
if (year == null) {
    year = String.format("%4d",now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    int mth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    month = String.format("%02d",mth);
    day = String.format("%02d",now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

String str_date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = (Date)format.parse(str_date);

calendar.setTime(date);
Date [] arrayOfDates = new Date[4];
arrayOfDates[0] = calendar.getTime();

pageContext.setAttribute("calendarDate",arrayOfDates);
pageContext.setAttribute("year",year);
pageContext.setAttribute("month",month);
pageContext.setAttribute("day",day);%>
```